# How to split any word without using reversed() and [::-1]

Tags: python-3.x

I have a task for split any string value without using reversed() and [::-1].

using [::-1] is too much easy but there is a task to get output without using it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

A ugly way is using

```
original_string = "abcde"
output = ""

for c in original_string:
    ouput = c + output
```

Answer (score 0):

split() is a method {you can call it as a function but methods are mapped using dot.}

```
>>>'Hello'.split() 
...['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>>list(reversed(list(reversed ('Hello'))))
...['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>>'Hello'[::-1]
 ...olleH
```

[More on split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554586/split-in-python)

[More on reversed() and [::-1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)